# Export data from a table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 45 millions from a mysql DB, i want to export those data in a .csv format, what is best way to do without affecting existing performance of other tables (when this operation is performed)?

Thanks.

Comment: Could be better asked at serverfault, but of course the major performance gain would be to do it on a replicated backup-server rather then the 'live' one.

Comment: If you right click and start exporting it will take much time, am thinking whether we can any other approach than this. Exporting 45 millions in a single attempt is not a good approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i figured it out,

to export 
->select * into outfile 'c:/tmp/outfile.txt' fields terminated by ',' from tablename;

To Import

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/tmp/outfile.txt' INTO TABLE newtablename
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_name into outfile '/tmp/output_file.csv';
```

However, you may face a problem  "Can't create/write to file", then you can do these following code.

```
USE mysql;
UPDATE user SET File_priv = 'Y' WHERE User = 'db_user';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then, you can export table.